# phpmyadmin show full sql output

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Seems phpmyadmin trims the end of the sql output when running operation commands .. 
I really need phpmyadmin to show the full output

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: Heh, not right off, but I compliment you on making it so clear where the problem lies.  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a quick search on Google i found this: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#MaxCharactersInDisplayedSQL

It seems that you just have to edit the config file of PHPmyadmin and set `$cfg['MaxCharactersInDisplayedSQL'] = 1000;` to the value you want.

Comment: Thank you I guess its a case of knowing what to look for because I searched for a good 15mins before turning to here

Answer (score 2):

My problem was even more simple.  I was using "show create table", but the result was truncated after a handful of chars.

PHPMyAdmin actually has a small `"+options"` link over the results, with simple options like "truncate results".  Just needed to untick that !

If you want to edit the files mentionned by Torr, look for :

- `config.default.php`, in 'librairies" folder, which contains existing parameters
- `config.inc.php`, where you should copy/paste the ones you need to.

Answer (score 0):

With phpMyAdmin version 5.2.1, [this solution](https://www.gonnalearn.com/how-to-display-full-query-results-in-phpmyadmin/) solved it for me:

1. Click on the "Extra Options" link above the results.
2. In the options menu, select "Full texts".
3. Click on Go to re-execute your query.

[image: phpMyAdmin screen]